# Activeadmin formtastic partial ordering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, formtastic

In an ActiveAdmin form, I have the following code:

```
render partial: "admin/lesson/recurring_adder", locals: { lesson: lesson, added_classes: "recurring-settings" }

t.input(:schedule,
  :as => :select, 
  input_html: { class: 'recurring_select recurring-settings'},
  wrapper_html: { class: "recurring-settings" },
  label: "Repeat Rule",
  collection: options_for_select( options, selected)
)

render partial: "admin/lesson_recurring/recurring_form", locals: { lesson_recurring: lesson_recurring, added_classes: "recurring-settings" }

render partial: "admin/lesson_recurring/affect_scope", locals: { lesson_recurring: lesson_recurring, added_classes: "recurring-settings" }
```

The problem is the `t.input` renders after all the partials instead of in order.

How do I get the t.input to render in between the partials?